# decompile a unity dll with Invalid RVA

Tags: c#, decompiling, decompiler, .net-reflector

I am trying to decompile a unity dll. The code is in Assembly-CSharp.dll.  Reflector says Invalid RVA Address '05b81455'. I assume they have been edited with something like unity3dobfuscator.  I've read there is a way to fix the RVA. I can't find any tutorials on how to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?  The end result I am looking for is to be able to open some dat files. If I can see the code I can read these files. So optionally can anyone help to deserialize a file you don't have a class for? I understand that it could also be encrypted. However I doubt it.

Here is the text from one of the dat files.

```
    BR”x   AkuaAkua     Š}Gbigpeez-fM-  ÿÿÿÿ    ƒ   
           ÿÿ„ËBÈ‚iC…~DúZ¹À^Þ3ÃÄ´@G“õÿ?ŠÔ’q–º       úC          úC  úC  úC    
                                  úC          úC  úC  úC    
                                  úC          úC  úC  úC    
                                  úC          úC  úC  úC    
                                  €?          €?  €?  €?    
                                   ² É!Ñòè­Ëþ(0Ï¶¦ó£êfÚ\¾&¯~=U5=¯ƒz Êœz­Ï¡îwÎ• ¾WÎxþ8ô¬4ýýÖ÷×jH®~=U5;Ëh0+DËœz­Ï!Ñ:«þ°Ïø@_¡·¦sœ™?©gI&÷zpH°Ÿ  ód¬Ï!ÑY  â³)0Ï¶¦sœÉ÷ñ}_ÈST5;‚ôiXÐ4z­Ï!ÑÙ               ÿÿ          }“Š>$m?  €?  €?    ¾å@>é
³>  €?  €?  €?  €?  €?  €?Êÿ?¿©<?  €?  (#      &        ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÙ   )   ¥  ÖC                            
                                                                                                                                   (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         „… ®q<ÿ4;ƒÕeÉû ¯¦#¹}Ûôrµ¬á+EÍÀ¤hqç›Â”¼{$$|<T6:†õÖë`zÂ{¦Î/ÐöÏžhØ·1V¦‹ëŒ†¾®s‚®­?è4òƒ2,f¼ÊV
®¬ å Û©`‘¬Ë+^ÍÙ¤™q‰8”þ®»$
nôWÿ9RöêûkwžªjÍÁõgØ|Žˆ1m·Õ>¾;b±¿Ð<Ï%‹ƒ[w³Ê]
¹¬
 ÛØçr ¬ö+®Í)¤×qW›n”h½   %úneEc+ÕäÁùˆk;Œ{‡ÍÓHT²ÛvŽý2ü¦’FŒ®¯¯s„¿B-h%’­rwäÛ?h¬H YžØqR¯ (½Î8§r˜.—ñ¿‘':«T¢:õ‚èýzP—{0Î¿Ð›ÑyÛ¿Ž;2J·µuž½ƒa¨1­f?L7!€ïõeeÉƒ   Z¯î#ó4Û»rü¬ª+Íž¤6q5›”É¼®$|W›9-ö«ëÖyyž¸xÍ—Ó³aÉÛŽ’22´XŒž™¼‹`¡¬\>q6ÜÃdWÈ²J®ý"ÂØŠqÄ¯’(³Î2§™r<˜
—Ù¿»'Tø:†öë`y»žzxßÍRÓpyÑÛŽŠ2k´Õž1½#a‰™­¾?”79÷õdeÈ½Y®ê"ö>Ú´sô­£*Ì‚¥*pªš‡•Z½?%”}V8¼÷$ê'xŠŸWxàÍoÓ_QùÛ$Žå2Í¦®xŒ•¯›s‡ª­}-Q%4’òìw|Û•p½Á1ÁÉ`Í¾ù3Ï†¤sœ™¿–Š}G}“Š>$m?  €?  €?    ¾å@>é
³>  €?   €?  €?  €?  €?  €?Êÿ?¿©<?  €?            ™OŒEÓH
```

Answer (score 1):

I can just suppose, that RVA repair is possible

- if you know the cause one was corrupted, like some specific malware
- if you know where this RVA is specified and what should be pointed
  with it.

Comment: I know neither. So i'd have to interpret what the correct RVA should be.

Comment: I also have the same problem when i try to decompile Fate Grand Order